# pEntity 'nameentity' already has a parent: 'Scene'. New parent: 'Scene'

Tags: android, andengine

:D
I've a problem with detach and attachChild..

```
scene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        @Override
        public void reset() { }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) {
// USELESS CODE
// USELESS CODE
// USELESS CODE     
            if (!SUPER){
                if (player.collidesWith(Blinky) ||
                    player.collidesWith(Pinky) ||
                    player.collidesWith(Inky) ||
                    player.collidesWith(Clyde)){
                        player.animate(new long[]{130,130,130,130,130,130}, 24, 29, false);
                        player.stopPlayer();
                }
            }
            else {
                if (player.collidesWith(Blinky)){
                    scene.detachChild(Blinky);
                    respawnGhost("Blinky");
                }
                else if (player.collidesWith(Pinky)){
                    scene.detachChild(Pinky);
                    respawnGhost("Pinky");
                }
                else if (player.collidesWith(Inky)){
                    scene.detachChild(Inky);
                    respawnGhost("Inky");
                }
                else if (player.collidesWith(Clyde)){
                    scene.detachChild(Clyde);
                    respawnGhost("Clyde");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

With this code i detach..

And with this:

```
private void respawnGhost(final String ghost){
    final Path RespawnPath = new Path(9).to(265, 295).to(225,295).to(225,255).to(305, 255).to(305, 295).to(225, 295).to(225,255).to(265,255).to(265,215);
    TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
    ITimerCallback Callback;

    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(5,true,Callback = new ITimerCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {


        if(ghost.compareTo("Blinky") == 0){
            scene.attachChild(Blinky);
            Blinky.registerEntityModifier(new PathModifier(10, RespawnPath, null, new IPathModifierListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPathStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointStarted(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathWaypointFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity, final int pWaypointIndex) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPathFinished(final PathModifier pPathModifier, final IEntity pEntity) {

                    Blinky.direction=4;
                    Blinky.ghostVel = (int)VELOCITY + 10;
                    Blinky.setVelocity((int)VELOCITY + 10,0);
                    Blinky.randDir = (int)(randRespawn.nextFloat() * 10)%3;
                }
            }));
        }
```

i RE-attach...

But when OnTimePassed() is called, TADAAAA!
Wild exception appeared :V

java.lang.IllegalStateException: pEntity 'Ghost' already has a parent: 'Scene'. New parent: 'Scene'!
at org.andengine.entity.Entity.assertEntityHasNoParent(Entity.java:1412)
at blablabla....

But if i comment:

```
//this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler = new  TimerHandler(5,true,Callback = new ITimerCallback(){

    ////    @Override
    ////    public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
```

all work fine...

Someone can help me? :)

ps: sorry for my really bad english ç.ç

Comment: Every entity has only one parent, and multiple children. When a entity  C is attached to entity P, C's parent is set to P and C is adding to the children list of P by AndEngine internally. From your code above, you have one entity called 'Blinky', but you attach it to scene multiple times. Maybe either change your timer to oneshot timer, or you need a Blinky pool, and attach a free Blinky to sense in your repeated timer.

Answer (score 0):

I partially understand your problem and try to give answer as best as possible.
First if you want to detach some entity from the scene then you have to use update handler like the following code describe.

```
mActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable(){

      public void run(){
           mScene.detachChild(mEntity);
      }
});
```

This is the preferred way to remove entity from the scene if you got any exception.

And you found IllegalStateException because you already attached that entity in to the scene. So if you try to attach same entity again this will fire an exception.

```
spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(5,true,new ITimerCallback(){});
```

I said above statement because you apply true in the timer handler so it calls multiple time. So same entity try to attach again and again.